Sequence of stars with colored regions
I was asked this in an internship application test for Deutsche bank. This was a few weeks ago and the application/quiz had closed.

What star should come next (and why)?

Can you provide proper attribution for this puzzle?

Internship for where? Did you finish the application?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Nice puzzle.

@bobble For Deutsche bank. This was a while a go - a few weeks. Applications have already closed for them and the question was a part of a time-controlled quiz (which I've already submitted-and ofc the deadline for the quiz has also passed).

I've edited the attribution into the question. Sorry about that, we've just had problems before.

@bobble nw, thanks for editing my post

I believe the next star should look like this:

 


 Each star has one white section in a different outer triangle. Since we are seeking to finish a sequence of five stars and there are five outer triangles, one could reasonably believe that the fifth star will have its white section in the past remaining outer triangle: the one in the bottom left.
 We can now order the white triangles, based on which star has white in that triangle. Graphing which star has which color in which triangle, we get the following matrix:
$\begin{array}\\W&B&G&B&G\\B&W&B&G&G\\G&B&W&G&B\\B&G&G&W&G\\?&?&?&?&W\end{array}$
 The entries given to us are all symmetric about the main diagonal. For the entire matrix to be symmetric, the last row must be $\begin{array}\\G&G&B&G&W\\\end{array}$.
 Since the center section is not part of this order, I see no reason not to assume it will continue to alternate between green and blue-with-white-dots.


The center could be white to balance 2g 2b 1w in each region

That would be another reasonable approach, except the bottom left triangle is green three times.
